# Pandas - styling tables with apply and applymap

Tags: python, pandas

I have this df_teams:

```
               ShortName Strength TeamColor
Team                                       
Arsenal              ARS        4   #EF0107
Aston Villa          AVL        2   #770038
Bournemouth          BOU        2   #D3151B
Brighton             BHA        2   #005DAA
Burnley              BUR        3   #630F33
Chelsea              CHE        4   #034694
Crystal Palace       CRY        3   #C4122E
Everton              EVE        3   #274488
Leicester            LEI        3   #0053A0
Liverpool            LIV        5   #CE1317
Man City             MCI        5   #97C1E7
Man Utd              MUN        4   #E80909
Newcastle            NEW        3   #231F20
Norwich              NOR        2   #00A14E
Sheffield Utd        SHU        3   #E52126
Southampton          SOU        3   #ED1A3B
Spurs                TOT        4   #132257
Watford              WAT        3   #FBEE23
West Ham             WHU        2   #7C2C3B
Wolves               WOL        4   #FDB913
```

And I want to print a table where each row has the team color.

I know I can use pandas `df_teams.style.applymap()` method for that.

I've tried:

```
st.table(df_teams.style.applymap(lambda x:df_teams['TeamColor'][x]))
```

Not working.

```
KeyError: 'ARS'
```

Also tried `apply()`:

```
st.table(df_teams.style.apply(lambda x:df_teams['TeamColor'][x], axis=0))
```

Not either:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

---

How do I do it?

The best way would be like having a dictionary of team colors, like so:

```
#A dictionary of team colors
team_colors = {'ARS':'#EF0107',
'AVL':'#770038',
'BOU':'#D3151B',
'BHA':'#005DAA',
'BUR':'#630F33',
'CHE':'#034694',
'CRY':'#C4122E',
'EVE':'#274488',
'LEI':'#0053A0',
'LIV':'#CE1317',
'MCI':'#97C1E7',
'MUN':'#E80909',
'NEW':'#231F20',
'NOR':'#00A14E',
'SHU':'#E52126',
'SOU':'#ED1A3B',
'TOT':'#132257',
'WAT':'#FBEE23',
'WHU':'#7C2C3B',
'WOL':'#FDB913'}
```

So I could just apply a function that maps from this dictionary, and not have colors as values in a column, which is undesired.

I've tried:

```
st.table(df_teams.style.applymap(lambda x:team_colors[x]))
```

But get:

```
KeyError: '4'
```

And passing `axis=0` or `axis=None`:

```
st.table(df_teams.style.apply(lambda x: team_colors[x], axis=0))
```

Not!

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a (kind of hacky) way to color the font, simply pass the entire data frame into a function to grab the `TeamColor`:

```
def colo(df):
    return ['color: {}'.format(df['TeamColor'])]*3 # ncols

df_teams.style.apply(colo, axis=1)
```

`axis=1` will pass the entire row to the function which allows us to color the entire row.

To color the background of the row using a column in the data frame, use this function:

```
def colo(df):
    return ['background-color: {}'.format(df['TeamColor'])]*3
```

If you'd like to use a dictionary outside the df:

```
def colo(df, dic):
    return ['background-color: {}'.format(dic[df['ShortName']])]*3

df_teams.style.apply(colo, dic=team_colors, axis=1)
```

The official documentation goes in to far more depth, see [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html).

Comment: hum, it works, but is it possible to have style as background gradient for the ROW, instead os coloring the font?

Comment: also, it must be `*3` (columns), because the other is the index.

Comment: the best way though, would be to map from the dictionary of colors (`team_colors` list i the question), because color codes shoud not remain as values when it is printed. is this possible as well?